# Is the Janaka of the Upanishads whose guru was Yajnavalkya the Janaka of Ramayana? If so, how does the Ramayana mention Vasishtha, a Vedic rishi?

Tags: ramayana, janaka, yajnavalkya

Is the Janaka of the Upanishads whose guru was Yajnavalkya the Janaka of Ramayana? If so, how does the Ramayana mention Vasishtha, a Vedic rishi, who did not live during Yajnavalkya's era but far before that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Did Yajnavalkya have discussion with Sita's father or with some other Janaka?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/36006/did-yajnavalkya-have-discussion-with-sitas-father-or-with-some-other-janaka)